# Create as many text fields as the number entered in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have one `TextField`. When I enter integer `4` then I want to create another 4 textfields in my view.

```
TextField("Count", value: $productCount, formatter: NumberFormatter())
ForEach(0..<$productCount) { element in
    VStack {
        Text("asd")
    }
}
```

Comment: Text or TextField?

Comment: oo sorry I wrote text but I needed to textfield.I solved my problem thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a demo of possible solution:

```
struct DemoView: View {
    @State private var productCount = 0
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Count", value: $productCount, formatter: NumberFormatter())
            VStack{
                ForEach(0..<productCount, id: \.self){element in
                    Text("asd")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```